# Can't create folder links from a fat32 partition

Tags: directory, symbolic-link, fat32

When I try to create links from several folders (created on windows 7) in order to put them on my personal folder, I get the following error:

> Error creating the link to [folder] - Destination does not support symbolic links
>
> Cancel / skip / skip everything

Answer (score 1):

The problem is only with using Nautilus, which creates the link in the same folder as the original, rather than in your home directory.  I don't know if Nautilus can do this, but you can do it using the commandline in a terminal with the "ln" command.

`ln -s /path/to/file_or_folder ~/name_of_link`

where

"/path/to/file_or_folder" is the complete path to the mounted folder,

"~/name_of_link" is the destination for the link in you home directory.